# Python: executing a complex command on windows

Tags: python, windows, command-line, python-fu

I am having a problem when running a command on Windows whereas it works perfectly on Linux.

I give you the context, but this is not necessary to understand my issue: I am using gimp in batch mode.

I have a Python script `callPythonFuScript.py` which calls another Python script, `pythonFu.py`, which executes a python-fu call.

In `callPythonFuScript.py`, I construct the command line when I call the function inside `pythonFu.py` to be executed. This is the command line:

```
gimp-console-2.8 -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b 'import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import pythonFu;pythonFu.myFunction("arg1","arg2","arg3") ' -b 'pdb.gimp_quit(1)'
```

This command works perfectly on Linux but when I try to run it on Windows, it does not work.

Error messages are:

```
The opening of C:\Users\myRep\sys; failed : no such file or directory
The opening of C:\Users\myRep\sys.path=['.']+sys.path; failed : no such file or directory
The opening of C:\Users\myRep\"arg1","arg2","arg3")' failed no such file or directory
```

I am assuming that Windows interprets characters differently than Linux. Is this correct? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does replacing ``'`` with ``"`` in your command line help?

Comment: No it does not.
If you know a bit of pythonfu -b '' execute one command
the first one does not work in any case ie -b 'import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;importpythonFu;pythonFu.myFunction("arg1","arg2","arg3") '
but the second one works ie -b 'pdb.gimp_quit(1)'
thanks for your answer
Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are having an escaping issue between what the command prompt sees as arguments, and what is being passed as a literal string for python to eval:

```
-b 'import sys;sys.path=["."]+sys.path;import pythonFu;pythonFu.myFunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")'
```

If that still gives you errors, it is possible you might need to escape the double quotes:

```
-b 'import sys;sys.path=[\".\"]+sys.path;import pythonFu;pythonFu.myFunction(\"arg1\",\"arg2\",\"arg3\")'
```

Comment: Thanks jdi,

But it still does not work, It was a good solution to avoid python making mistakes with the double quotes.
But then the correct string ie -b 'import sys;sys.path=["."]+sys.path;import pythonFu;pythonFu.myFunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")' is given to windows command line and it interprets the double quotes differently from shell.
I am assuming this is the problem but I do not know how to correct it.

I think the first step is correct but now I have to make sur that the string giben by python is well interpreted by windows

thanks again,

victor

Comment: To figure your way around, I'd start by hacking a python script which just prints argv to stdout. You can then play around with windows command line processing by comparing your input and the scripts output.